# Default Homepage of Demo can't be overided

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have installed the Virtue wordpress theme and when i want to override the default front page of the demo with the one customized by me, the default homepage keeps on coming back. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **dashboard** > **Settings** > **Reading**

Should be under this link : http://yoursite/wp-admin/options-reading.php

Find **Your homepage displays** from reading settings and check the option  **static page (select below)** then from **Homepage** select the page that you want to display as your home page, then save.